# Show that exists an epimorphism $\phi_i: T \rightarrow G_i$ and find $\ker(\phi_i)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-homomorphism, direct-product

Let $G_1,...,G_n$ be groups and $T:=G_1× \cdots × G_n$.

Show that $ \forall i \in \{1, \cdots , n \} $ exists an epimorphism $\phi_i: T \rightarrow G_i$ and  find
$\ker(\phi_i)$.

I'm not sure if what I have done is correct:

Let $\phi_i (g_1, \cdots , g_n) = g_i $ for $i\in \{ 1, \cdots , n\}$

We want to see first if $\phi$ is a homomorphism, so let's consider:

$(g_1, \cdots , g_n),(h_1, \cdots , h_n) \in T$

then

$\phi_i ((g_1, \cdots , g_n) \cdot (h_1, \cdots , h_n)) = \phi_i ((g_1h_1, \cdots , g_nh_n)) = g_ih_i$

$\Rightarrow \phi_i (g_1, \cdots , g_n) \phi_i(h_1, \cdots , h_n) = g_ih_i $

And now we want to see $\phi_i$ is surjective. Consider $g_i \in G_i$

$\Rightarrow \phi_i (e, \cdots , g_i , \cdots, e) = g_i$

And since then, $\phi_i$ is surjective. On the other hand

$\ker(\phi_i)=\{ (g_1, \cdots , g_{i-1}, e , g_{i+1}, \cdots , g_n) | g_i \in G_i \}$

Comment: It looks just fine. Projections from direct products (in this case, also cartesian product) to their factors always work fine.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I'm new on this platform, sorry about that. I've already "accepted" your answer. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your solution is fine.

These homomorphisms are natural consequences of the [universal property](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property) of the direct product.